# Brown spots on wooden furniture

Tags: furniture

I've started to notice these brown stains that are occurring on my wooden furniture, and it happens in obscure places, I doubt this is dirt. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Said wooden furniture but the picture looks like a top corner of a wall.  Type of wood and finish would help.

Comment: If no water leaks, behind/on top, might be bug waste or some type of fungus/mold growing.  Try cleaning with soapy water with some bleach/disinfectant in it.

Comment: how big is this photo of?  how old is the furniture? is that paint the original surface finish?

Comment: That's actually wooden cabinet's corner. I did assume it's fungus/mold but can't seem to figure out what kind.

Comment: Most fungus/mold need to be tested to tell the right type.  A picture might only limit it to a hundred types, instead of thousands.  Bleach usually does not care what type, it kills most of them.

Comment: It reminds me more of "fly speck" ... insect dung....